# Cakephp 3.6.14: Enable button if selection input has value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a selection control in my code and 2 submit buttons. How I can hide or disable one of the buttons if no selection has be done in the selection box?

Here is the code:

```
//selection box
echo $this->Form->control('assigned_to',['options' => $usersTo, 'empty' => true, 'value' => $selectedUser]);

//submit buttons

<?= $this->Form->submit(__('Direct Assign'), ['name' => 'btn', 'class' => 'button']) ?> 
//this must be disabled or hidden if selection box is empty


<?= $this->Form->submit(__('Save'), ['name' => 'btn', 'class' => 'button']) ?>
```

Comment: With js / jquery? If selected then enable , else disable button

Comment: @Salines can you provide code?

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you shouldn't use Form->submit, the form has one submit
   button, i think you should use postlink instead. Also change the
   name and create different id for the buttons.
2. Second you can do this using jquery, you will listen on your select
   control change event and disable & enable or do what you want to do
   to other controls

> ```
> <?php
> $this->start("scriptBottom");
> ?>
> <script>
> $(document).ready(function () {
>      $("assigned-to").change(function ()
>      {
>           var selected = $("#assigned-to option:selected").text();
>           if(selected == 'OPTION 1')
>           {
>                  $("#btn").prop('disabled');
>           }
>           //do other things
> }
> });
> </script>
>
> <?php
> $this->end();
> echo $this->fetch('scriptBottom');
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Can you'd a bit more detail to this code example, such as checking the value of the selection, for instance?

Comment: var selected = $("#assigned-to option:selected").text();
this is how to get the current selected item  from the control. Please check the modified example again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to do the same:

```
//selection box
echo $this->Form->control('assigned_to',['options' => $usersTo, 'empty' => true, 'value' => $selectedUser, 'id' => 'assigned_to']);

//submit buttons

<?= $this->Form->submit(__('Direct Assign'), ['name' => 'btn', 'class' => 'button', 'id' => 'direct_assign']) ?> 
//this must be disabled or hidden if selection box is empty


<?= $this->Form->submit(__('Save'), ['name' => 'btn', 'class' => 'button']) ?>


    $(document).ready(function(){
// check the value of assign selection box when document is ready
     let assignedValue = $("#assigned_to").val(); // get the value of assign selection box
      if(assignedValue == '') {
       $("#direct_assign").attr('disabled', true) // to disable direct assign button 
      }
    })
```

Hope this will help!